# moving the key of an object into its value to create an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

I have an object I want to build a table out of however I need to use the value of the key as a part of the data displayed. My data looks like this:

```
{
    templates: {
      some_visit_1: {
        template: "A long block or rich text",
        editedAt: "timestamp",
        editedBy: "name",
      },
      some_visit_2: {
        template: "A different block of rich text",
        editedAt: "timestamp",
        editedBy: "Name",
      },
    },
  },
```

Ive tried using

```
let data = result.templates;
const templates = Object.entries(data);
```

But this gives me nested arrays inside with the key as one value and an object as the second. I would like to create an array of objects where each object contains the key and all values inside the initial object.

Taking this a step further I thought I could map over the new array and spread the data into an object but this just causes errors.

```
const templates = Object.entries(data).map((item, idx) => {
        const values = item[1];
        return {
          ...items,
          items: {
            name: item[0],
            editedAt: item[1].editedAt,
            editedBy: item[1].editedBy,
            template: item[1].template,
          },
        };
      });
```

Is there a method to combine the key and all values in an object into a single object?

like this:

```
[
   {
       {
        name: some_visit_1,
        template: "A long block or rich text",
        editedAt: "timestamp",
        editedBy: "name",
      },
      {
        name: some_visit_2,
        template: "A different block of rich text",
        editedAt: "timestamp",
        editedBy: "Name",
      }
]
```

Comment: What is your expected output if you have another key in your outermost object (such as `templates2`) with a nested object similar to the one you have now for `templates`, or is that not a possible case. Your expected output currently has an additional `{` which would throw a syntax error (not sure if this is there by mistake or whether you intended your objects to be wrapped in some sort of container?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what is expected?. I used `Object.entries` and `map`

```js
let data = {
  templates: {
    some_visit_1: {
      template: "A long block or rich text",
      editedAt: "timestamp",
      editedBy: "name",
    },
    some_visit_2: {
      template: "A different block of rich text",
      editedAt: "timestamp",
      editedBy: "Name",
    },
  },
}
let result = Object.entries(data.templates).map(([key, value]) => {
  return {
    name: key,
    ...value,

  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: First time I see `map(([key, value]) => {` could you explain how it works?

Comment: @Gass [Object.entries returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#return_value) an array of key and values of each item in the object. So the return of `Object.entries` will be an array of arrays example:  `[ [key1,  value of key1], [key2, value of key2], [key3, value of key key 3]  ]`  - continued in 2nd comment

Comment: @Gass (cont...) When we use a map the first argument will the the current element which is iterated by the `map`. So we can either access the element like  `.map(item=> {})`  and get the key by `item[0]` and value by `item[1]`  or we can use like `.map(([key, value])=> {})` . This is basically [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the array.

Comment: Super clear, thank you